# laravel custom error display

Tags: php, laravel

I have a weird problem.
The thing is, I'm trying to display errors if validation fails. When I add the function that checks if there are any errors it throws me this

Call to a member function has() on string
in 1a9e38a37f43696e36d945eadb85a60fed28183b.php (line 28)

Which is this:

```
  @if($errors->has('credentials') > 0)
    <p class="error">{{ $errors->first('credentials') }}</p>
  @endif
```

This is how I'm handling validation

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'credentials' => 'required',
        'password' => 'required',
    ]);

    $user_detail = $request->credentials;
    $password = $request->password;

    if(Sentinel::authenticate(array('login' => $user_detail, 'password' => $password)))
    {
        return redirect()->route('site.index');
    }
    else 
    {
        return back()->with('errors', 'test');
    }
}
```

Comment: `errors` has value `test`, what do you expect?

Comment: So what? That should be returned if the validation passes and authentication doesn't. I deleted that whole line and I'm still having the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Using

```
return back()->with('errors', 'test');
```

you create variable `$errors` with **string** value `"test"`.

But `has` (and `first` too) is a method of [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/master/collections#method-has). So, you need to have `$errors` as collection:

```
return back()->with('errors', collect(['credentials' => 'Error text goes here']));
```

Comment: Tried that already still the same. FatalErrorException
Call to a member function has() on string
in 1a9e38a37f43696e36d945eadb85a60fed28183b.php (line 28) which is the first code snipper i provided.

Comment: You have error in your code. I created `errors` as __collection__, so there will be __no__ error about string.

Answer (score 0):

what about using

```
return back()->withErrors('test');
```